# Update JOINED Table with Most Recent Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, constructor, sql-update

So I'm stumped.  I have two tables I'm joining together and updating one of them.  Now, I want to update it with the **MOST RECENT** record of data.

So I want this to occur first (this ordering):

```
select * from APUL 
order by UIMth desc
```

Followed by this update:

```
UPDATE APUI
SET    APUI.udTempReviewer = APUL.ReviewerGroup
FROM   APUI 
  INNER JOIN APUL ON APUI.UISeq = APUL.UISeq 
                 AND APUI.APCo = APUL.APCo
```

So basically I want to update table APUI with the most recent record from APUL, as APUL is an invoice record table.

Comment: Please show some sample data for these tables.  Are you trying to `APUI` with the most recent record from `APUL` for *each* record?  Or are you only interested in the most recent `APUL` record, period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Row_Number` window function

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER(partition BY uiseq, apco ORDER BY uimth DESC ) AS rn, 
                reviewergroup, 
                uiseq, 
                apco 
         FROM   apul) 
UPDATE A 
SET    A.udtempreviewer = L.reviewergroup 
FROM   apui A 
       INNER JOIN CTE L 
               ON A.uiseq = L.uiseq 
                  AND A.apco = L.apco 
Where L.Rn = 1
```

Comment: Where do I put this WITH CTE thing?  Like where in the query?

Comment: @MattGordon - It is a single query.. You don't have to do anything

Comment: Doesn't work homie.  L.apco isn't pulling up anything and is throwing an error

Comment: Also, don't abbreviate table names.  It's pathetic

Comment: @MattGordon - check now...Dude try some debugging.. Those are simple mistakes

Comment: `WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER(partition BY UISeq ORDER BY UIMth DESC ) AS rn, 
                ReviewerGroup, 
                UISeq 
         FROM   APUL) 
UPDATE APUI 
SET    APUI.udTempReviewer = CTE.ReviewerGroup 
FROM   APUI 
       INNER JOIN CTE 
               ON APUI.UISeq = CTE.UISeq 
Where CTE.rn = 1`